# Background image zooms in using -webkit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit

Can anyone help with this? I'm not sure if I posted the correct code for a test on here but basically I'm using a background image on body with this code, it works good but when I click on any other pages the background image zooms in?

```
#1a2a40 url(images/deluxe/hmid.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50% fixed; }
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Also i should add, i want the bg image to scroll with the page.. not just the background to scroll?

Comment: can you provide a link to the web page or just reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

On the `index.php` page, the height is around 1000px, while on the `memberlist.php` the height is over 2700px.

## Possible solutions

- I think you should split your image: one for the top of the page, one for the bottom and one `repeated` in the middle of the page.
  With this setup, you can have page with different size, but with a default background image.
- Fix the background of the page

  `background-position: 50% 0; background-attachment: fixed;`

Comment: Hmm i've used this code before on the same setup near enough and had no problems with it. any other way to make it stop zooming in?